# Service Fabric with Window Containers

Tags: docker, azure-service-fabric, windows-container

I was wondering how the containers running inside a service fabric cluster communicate with each other. I have two containers, one backend and one front end. I need to pass the IP address/DNS of the backend node to the front end container. Does anybody know how I can do this? 
Other docker orchestration tools like swarm mode and Kubernetes use DNS and you just pass the service name.

Answer (score 2):

As of now, you need to use environment variables to do this. However, we'll be adding DNS support in an upcoming release to make this easier.

Comment: Do you know how to pass in docker volumes via service fabric? E.g. -v c:\test:c:\test

Answer (score 0):

There is specific documentation about container discovery here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-container
I did not try it but it seems what you are looking for which is container to container discovery

Comment: Thanks but I have seen this document and still doesn't make sense. Do I need to update my container image now to commuicate with the reverse proxy?

Comment: You will pass service endpoint in environment variable to your container during start up to identify where your backend service is. You will have to modify your container obviously to rely on this environment variable. I assume it's normal practice in other cluster orchestration services.